# spark streaming and spark sql considerations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark stream (scala) and receiving records of customer calls to a call center through kafka after every 20 minutes. Those records are converted in rdd and later dataframe to exploit spark sql. I have a business use case where I want to identify all the customers who called more than 3 times in the last two hours.

What would be the best approach to do that? Should I keep inserting  in a hive table all the records received in every batch and run a separate script to keep querying who did 3 calls in last two hours or there is another better using spark in memory capabilities ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of use case you can get the result using spark (There is no requirement of hive). You must have some customer unique id, so you can prepared some query like

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY time DESC) as call_count
```

and you have to apply filter for last 2 hours data with `call_count=3` so you can get your expected result. Then you can set this spark script into crontab or any other autorun methods.

Comment: Thanks  @Sahil. But I receive data in batches say every 20 minutes. I get RDDs and convert them to dataframes and then tempview. By this logic my tempview will only contain the last RDD. How to ensure that I am saving the results of all the RDDs which come in different batches and then apply logic of row_number() Below is my sample

Comment: AirDRStream.foreachRDD(foreachFunc = rdd => {
      System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.count() + " records");

        val sqlContext = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
          .getOrCreate()
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        rdd.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("AIR")
       
        val FilteredDR = sqlContext.sql("select refillProfileID, count(*) from AIR group by refillProfileID")
        FilteredDR.show()